# Flutter Null Safety Migration - Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

We are running flutter null safety migration and completed the same but while running the app we are facing **Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

```
static Future<AppStrings> getAppText(String local) async {
var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");
 AppStrings appText = new AppStrings(
  mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'), ==> error on this line 
  ....
);
return appText;}
```

I've tried adding **static Future<AppStrings?>** && **AppStrings? appText** as suggested in other solutions but it throws further error
`Error: The argument type 'AppStrings?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AppStrings' because 'AppStrings?' is nullable and 'AppStrings' isn't.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `AppStrings` is but it seems that `mainPageTitle` in there is a `String` and `appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle')` is returning `null` and you can't do that.

There's two possible options:

1. Make `mainPageTitle` in `AppStrings` nullable, by change the `String` there to `String?`. This probably requires you to make additional changes in your code to handle it being nullable, so it easier to do the second option.
2. Or, you make it fall back to empty string in the case it's `null`. This can be done by writing `mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle') ?? ''`

Comment: tried setting default value using the second options as well as tried  as below mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle',defaultValue:'') , both opens up a empty screen since its only taking up the default values in the app now

Comment: @HARIPRASAD that would be a different issue then. I only answered this specific problem. As to why you only get default values is a different problem that can't be answered with the info you provide and also you should be asked as a separate question

Comment: is it possible if i could provide the AppStrings Models & its implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static Future<AppStrings> getAppText(String local) async {
var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");
 AppStrings appText = new AppStrings(
  mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle') ?? "",
  ....
);
return appText;}
```

Comment: if i add "" as default values , its not taking up dynamic values and ending up with a empty page in app :(

Comment: So you need to make sure that there is a value always for this key in local storage because mainPageTitle should not be null anytime.

Comment: any examples of above implementation as im rookie with flutter